Fetching BlockNumber for heap tuple insertion in PostgreSQL
Suppose I run this SQL query:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(20)
);
INSERT into my_table(id, value) VALUES (1,'hey')

This will insert this new row as a heap tuple in PostgreSQL.
To insert this row, the following steps will happen on a high level:

Acquire ROW EXCLUSIVE LOCK
Fetch Relation Data from system catalogs table if not cached in relcache.
Appropriate BlockNumber will be selected for insertion
The data is written into that Page.

Now for point 3, Postgres uses the method: RelationGetBufferForTuple
In case BulkInsertState is false, postgres gets the block using: the RelationGetTargetBlock method which is essentially:
#define RelationGetTargetBlock(relation) \
    ( (relation)->rd_smgr != NULL ? (relation)->rd_smgr->smgr_targblock : InvalidBlockNumber )

If have questions regarding this:

The RelationGetTargetBlock method isn't thread safe, what if multiple writers are using this targblock, and then updating it using the RelationSetTargetBlock method? I see no lock acquired before accessing RelationData or specifically SMgrRelationData
RelationSetTargetBlock method too isnt thread safe in case of multiple writers.
If this block is filled already, postgres extends the relation using RelationAddBlocks method, but in case of multiple writers, wont the relation keep getting extended, since lot of inserts might have picked up a stale target block.

I tried inspecting if any locks are acquired to access RelationData but didnt found anything conclusive. Also extending the relation with one more block could potentially extend Relation Blocks by more than 1.

"This will insert this new row as a heap tuple in PostgreSQL"  - Not necessarily, show us your CREATE TABLE my_table first.

@Dai I have fixed and replaced double quotes with single quotes. Though I am more concerned with backend working of insertion of heap tuple in postgres

@Dai added the create table command in the question.

I didn't say anything about quotes....

Why do you mention the id in the insert, when id is a serial? (using a sequence, that will now cause conflicts) Better to use an identity column

A question about the code of PostgreSQL itself should imho be asked at the mailinglist where the programmers are: https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/

RelationGetTargetBlock doesn't need to be thread-safe, as the variable does not live in shared memory AFAICT.  It is backend-private and backends are not threaded.  I assume the same applies to RelationSetTargetBlock but I haven't bothered to look into it.
RelationAddBlocks is only called when GetPageWithFreeSpace has failed, and when a retry loop has also failed.

Thanks @jjanes. "does not live in shared memory" What exactly it mean by private variable, since my understanding is RelationData object is for a relation OID. What happens if same client calls insert on that relation concurrently. If this is the case, the value smgr_targblock might be stale.
Also GetPageWithFreeSpace is used if use_fsm is true.

Backends are not threaded.  If the same "client" calls insert simultaneously, it must be juggling two separate connections, attached to two backends, maintaining two separate copies of the cache object.  use_fsm is almost always true, the only time it isn't is during something like VACUUM FULL I think.
